# Different padding in firefox and chromium within a flexbox

Tags: css, html, flexbox

Consider the following example:

https://jsfiddle.net/c9pky9v1/

This renders the same in Firefox 52.0 and Chromium 56.0

Now just add this:

```
#content > * {
    padding-top: 15%;
    padding-bottom: 15%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/p3nrkgoq/

suddenly the rendered site diverges:

Chromium:
[image: Padding in chromium]

Firefox:
[image: Padding in firefox]

Why is that and how can it be prevented?

Consider that this reset was already applied in vain:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Even though I don't really know the problem, maybe you want to use flexbox to center your content vertically? https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: How does it act in other browsers?  If we knew it acted the same in all EXCEPT a specific one, it would narrow down the problem a lot.

Comment: @Dave no idea. These are the only two browser I use/have access to. Maybe others can shed some light onto this.

Comment: @Lumio Thanks, but no, that's not what I intend. Actually I am just curious. I got permission by another user from another question to ask this, when I answered their question and this strange bug appeared. So it's just curiousity that led me here.

Comment: So question is a duplicate, but it cannot be prevented unless using e.g. `display:table` instead of flex?